# Installing Ubuntu within XP

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox, windows-xp

Recently my laptop with Ubuntu installed on it, finally gave up.
I have removed the HDD and mounted it in an external casing and plugged it in to my desktop which runs WinXp.

On my Ubuntu machine I had WinXp installed within Ubuntu using Virtualbox.

I know I can do the reverse on my WinXP machine, but what I was wondering was whether I can use VirtualBox to use my existing Ubuntu installation on the external drive?

Thanks
Alexis

Comment: "Finally gave up" -> please be more specific

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking whether you are able to boot your installed ubuntu installation as a virtual machine using virtual box;

Directly with no work required you are unable to do this as it is a physical installation and not a bootable image, that said;

There is a way that you are able to make a live CD/DVD of a physical installation that you could then use to boot into using virtualbox.

The method is rather lengthy but you can read about it on the [ubuntu forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=688872)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method to get to your desired end state would be to set up a dual boot of Ubuntu/XP on your desktop PC.  Then you could copy all your data from the old hard drive into the new Ubuntu install.

My #1 option for you would be to install Ubuntu instead of XP on the desktop and then copy the files, but I realize you may have some XP stuff you need to keep.

Setting up a dual boot with XP is way easier than it is with the newer versions.  It's also way easier than trying to extract your old Ubuntu to a virtual machine.